# How to make If statement with range of numbers - MatLab

Tags: matlab, if-statement, range

I'm trying to generate an action potential of the HH model, and I need to calculate the alphaN rates.  However, at a few values, they are 0/0, so I need to use L'hopitals rule.  I can't seem to make the script work. Can anyone please help?
How do I do an if statement for a range of numbers?  Like:

```
    if Vm == -50:-49
       syms Vm;
       x = diff((0.01.*(10-(Vm+60))));
       y = diff((exp((10-(Vm+60))./10)-1));
       alphaN  = x./y;
    else
       alphaN =  (0.01.*(10-(Vm+60)))./(exp((10-(Vm+60))./10)-1);  % l/ms
       betaN  = 0.125*exp(-(Vm+60)/80);                            % 1/ms
    end
       plot(alphaN,Vm)
```

However, with the above script, I get matrix doesn't agree. How can I make this work?  Hopefully it's just something I'm forgetting.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: First you test a variable, and then you define it?!

Comment: How would you approach it?

Answer (score 3):

To test whether `Vm` is between `a` and `b`, you write

```
if Vm >= a && Vm <= b %# include a and b
```

To test whether `Vm` is any integer between `a` and `b`

```
if any(Vm == a:b)
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but I'm getting a double error.  I'm not sure why.  Sorry if I'm bad with matlab.. maybe I'm missing something easy?  Like I said to thewaywewalk, my values of VM range from -60 to 80. I'm just trying to tell matlab that between -51 to -49, take the derivative of the top and the bottom, bc if Matlab doesn't, it'll be 0/0 = NaN

Comment: @user2137295: the thing is, your errors are not really related to that question. You need to break down your code to a simple case, just get it work for `Vm=-49`` and then another single value. Then you can try the loop or, if your exceptions are consecutive, the approach of jonas

Comment: Ok, Jonas and thewaywewalk, I will try a different approach and get back to you! thanks you both.

Comment: To check if Vm is between [a, b], shouldn't the conditional be `if Vm >= a && Vm <= b`?

Comment: @Wallacoloo: you're absolutely right. Thank you for spotting this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch/case construct:

```
Vm_all = -50:50;   %all Vm

for ii = 1:length(Vm)           
    Vm = Vm_all(ii);

    switch Vm
        case {-50,-49}
            syms Vm;
            x           = diff((0.01.*(10-(Vm+60))));
            y           = diff((exp((10-(Vm+60))./10)-1));
            alphaN(ii)  = x./y;
            betaN(ii)   = NaN;
        otherwise
            alphaN(ii)  =  (0.01.*(10-(Vm+60)))./(exp((10-(Vm+60))./10)-1); 
            betaN(ii)   = 0.125*exp(-(Vm+60)/80);                          
    end
end
```

This way it doesn't matter if your particular values are in a row or whatever, just type them comma separated.

If you have an array with your exceptions like `exc = [-50,-49,-12,42]` you can use it as follow for switch/case:

```
case {exc(:)}
```

Comment: I tried this method, but now it is telling me that error using mupadmex. error in line 12 with x./y;.  My values of Vm range from -60 to 80

Comment: it's an error of the symbolic math toolbox, which I don't have. Please try your equations without any loop.